# Хранение данных в Django

Tags: python, база-данных, django

В Django-приложении я использую PostgreSQL для хранения данных. В базе данных есть таблица User, в которой хранятся пользователи, их много. Но также я хочу хранить в базе пользовательское соглашение и иметь возможность его редактировать и отображать на сайте. Пользовательское соглашение может быть только одно, одинаковое для всех пользователей, поэтому создавать для него отдельную модель мне кажется неправильным. Из этого возникает вопрос: есть ли иные возможности хранить данные в Django-приложениях в виде ключ-значение (JSON, словарь)?

Comment: Объясните, что за данные и причём тут python и django

Comment: В django приложении я использую postgresql для хранения данных. В базе даннх  есть модель User в  которой хранятся пользователи их много. Но так же я хочу хранить в базе пользовательское соглашение и иметь возможность его редактировать и выводить на сайте. Пользовательское соглашение может быть только одно, одинаковое для всех пользователей и по этому создавать для него отдельную модель мне кажется неправильным. Из этого возникает вопрос есть ли иные возможности хранить данные в django приложениях по примеру - ключь значение (JSON, словарь)

Comment: Укажите это в вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Comment: А зачем Вам для того, что есть в единственном экземпляре и по большому счету не является сущностью какое-то хранилище? Ведь есть же диск, такие вещи можно хранить просто в текстовом файле, однако, если у Вас не один текстовый ресурс, не только соглашение, то как раз для них можно создать табличку в БД, а кроме того, если в Вашем приложении подразумевается интернационализация, то для каждого поддерживаемого языка нужна своя версия текстового ресурса.

Comment: Да можно создать отдельную таблицу, например TextTable, которая будет хранить текстовые ресурсы например одна запись для соглашения, другая для контактов, третья для FAQ. Но тогда возникает вопрос как их идентифицировать. Я думал о том что можно в нее добавить ещё одно поле с выбором типа записи, но все равно получается не гибко. То есть записи будут ограничиваться заранее заданными типами

Comment: @ivan, создайте таблицу с двумя varchar-полями: key и value, в value -- сам текст, а в key -- текстовый ключ (agreement, contacts, faq...), собственно, по этому ключу и идентифицировать, если нужна интернационализация, добавляете третье поле locale (ru, en, kz...), в этом случае у сущности будет составной первичный ключ из двух полей: key и locale. А что Вы имеете в виду под типом записи и почему то негибко?

Comment: @ivan у пользовательского соглашения могут быть старые и новые версии текста, поэтому создавайте модель для хранения всех версий :) Ну а TextTable логичнее уже назвать просто Page (или StaticPage по вкусу) и идентифицировать по slug

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы. Для моей задачи подошла библиотека django-dynamic-preferences. Возможно кому-то пригодится